# Send the value of the height of a div in a database

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to send the value of the height of a div in movement in my database. With the the code below it doesn't work. Someone see the problem?

I have another small problem. In the example, the value will never stop to be send to the database. I would stop recording when the button "stop" is pressed. Maybe in using the span Status below?

**html :**

This two buttons will activate the movement of the div

```
<input type="button" id="record" value="Record">
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop">

<div id="levelbar"></div>
```

// BELOW IT'S JUST INDICATORS

// The status pass to 1 when the button "record" is pressed.

```
<div> Status: <span id="status">0</span> </div>
```

// The level indicate the height of the div

```
<div> Level: <span id="level">0</span> </div>
```

// The timer is launched and stopped when one of the buttons is pressed.

```
<div> Time: <span id="time">0</span> </div>
```

**Script :**

```
<script>
function ajaxFunction(){
    var height = $("#levelbar")[0].getClientRects()[0].height;
     $.post("acceptfile.php", {height: height}); 
}
</script>
```

**Php (acceptfile.php) :**

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";
$dbname = "cheer";

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
$height = $_POST['height'];
$height = mysql_real_escape_string($height);

$query = "SELECT * FROM level WHERE height = '$height'";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Thanks,
Bastien

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `$("#levelbar").height()`? I'm fairly sure jQuery has that. *(Disclaimer: I don't use jQuery myself)*

On your second question: create a variable like `var isRecording = true;` which is then set to `false`. In your `ajaxFunction`, check for this variable. Make sure to put it on the global scope though (that means: put the variable outside the function so that it actually persists between function calls).

Comment: I'm using "var height = $("#levelbar")[0].getClientRects()[0].height;" because it's the only solution I found to transfer the value to the php file. (I am just a beginner with ajax and php).

Comment: If you have some time could you write a small example? I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

I've found issues before using a setup like this:

`{height: height}`

I fixed it by changing it to something along these lines:

`{height_post: height}`

Obviously would need to change it in the PHP script as well. I'm also noticing that you're doing a select query, not an insert or update query, which won't do anything for you if you're trying to update settings in your database. And if you're not, then you're not going to retrieve anything because you're not echoing the information back to the AJAX function.

The question itself is vague, and I was tempted to vote it down, but I thought I'd grasped the idea, so I went ahead and posted this. Let me know if it's anywhere near what you're looking for.